# Susyone no longer working as expected after update

Tags: sass, susy-compass

I have been running susy-2.1.2 with `@import "susyone";` instead of `@import "susy";`. Everything was working. I had to update compass through GEM which meant Sass had to update, which meant susy had to update too. So now i'm running susy-2.2.1.

I have this css:

```
.dropdown .susy_container{
    //Get ready for grids with bigger screen sizes
    $total-columns: 12;  // a 12-column grid
    $column-width: 100em;  // each column
    $gutter-width: 1em !global;  // gutters between columns
    $grid-padding: 0em !global ;
    @include container;
}
```

With the old version I would get this:

```
.dropdown .susy_container {
   max-width: 1211em;
   _width: 1211em;
   padding-left: 0em;
  padding-right: 0em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

With the new version I get this:

```
.dropdown .susy_container {
  max-width: 59em;
  _width: 59em;
  padding-left: 0em;
  padding-right: 0em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I also have strange gutters between columns. I am 100% sure I am using `susyone.scss`.

I wish I could go back to the old version of susy, but I get this:

```
Gem::LoadError on line ["2064"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.1.2, because sass-3.4.9 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
```

Comment: As a quick fix, you could try version 2.1.3. According to the [changelog](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/changelog/#jul-16-2014), it should work with Sass 3.4, but there are few other changes compared to 2.1.2.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have tried 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a change in Susy, it's a change in Sass. Looks like you need the `!global` flag on all the settings for them to take effect:

```
.dropdown .susy_container{
    //Get ready for grids with bigger screen sizes
    $total-columns: 12 !global;  // a 12-column grid
    $column-width: 100em !global;  // each column
    $gutter-width: 1em !global;  // gutters between columns
    $grid-padding: 0em !global ;
    @include container;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I felt like the switch to !global with scss was a long time ago, because i had this issue with Bootstrap. Maybe susy just started to care with 2.1.3.

Comment: Not sure what changed. That's not something we have any control over inside Susy.